# Broke my apt-get with texlive installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, latex, texlive

I was trying to update my TeXLive installation to 2017 version and followed the guide given [here](http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2016/10/31/install_tex_live_2016_on_ubuntu_16_04.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2017
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

It took a couple hours to download stuff, but the installation errored out with broken pipe error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-recommended_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-recommended-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-science_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-science-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-base_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now when I try to run, `apt-get -f install`, I get the same error with a bunch of texlive unmet dependencies and my apt-get is completely broken. I can't install any package using `apt-get install`.

I wish to completely remove `texlive` and reinstall it. I tried the steps given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu), which says to run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/* and rm -rf ~/.texlive*
rm -rf /usr/local/share/texmf
rm -rf /var/lib/texmf
rm -rf /etc/texmf
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge
rm -rf ~/.texlive
find -L /usr/local/bin/ -lname /usr/local/texlive/*/bin/* | xargs rm
```

No luck with above methods, since anything I run with `apt-get` gives me the unmet dependencies error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -P textlive`

Comment: @George, I did that and it says that `Removing texlive (2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0) `, and apparently it removed it. `sudo dpkg -r texlive-` gives around 40 auto-completions, do I need to manually remove each one using `dpkg -r`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, `dpkg` doesn't play nice with `*` wildcards. And you always use a script to so.

Comment: @George, ok if I try removing individually e.g. `sudo dpkg -P texlive-binaries`, it tells me that `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of texlive-binaries:` and lists a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then try again

Comment: Running that, tells me: `dependency problems - leaving unconfigured` for a long list of packages.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @George I think that just worked :) I removed individual `texlive-` packages, with dependencies and `apt-get` is now up and running. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to repair your apt-get:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then, remove all texlive packages.